# Windows Phone - WCF - cannot refresh webservice call

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I have a WCF web service, and a windows phone application.
The phone app's home page has a WCF ("GET") call I would like to refresh every 30 seconds.

No matter what happens to the data on the back end... the call to the WCF service will always return the data from the original call to the WCF service.

If i go to another page, and make the same call I will get the different modified data.
Is there some kind of caching on "GET" calls on the phone side?

**Debugger**
I do not think it is even going to the WCF to make the call.
My debugger looks like it's not even hitting the WCF again when I try to refresh.  The HTTPWebRequest just spits out the oroginal GET call if i am on that same page.

**Details**
WCF - webHTTPBinding (REST)

Comment: Might want to show some of the client code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...
There must be some Magic Caching on windows phone going.

I recall reading on some other thread a while back and tried it.... and it worked !!

Basically i'm just adding a unique id that doesn't matter to he URI string.  In the case below.. i decided to use a GUID... this way each call uses a unique different URI for the REST call.  It seems to work.

string uri = RESTCon.BaseString + "RESTMethodCallName?id={0}";
w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format(this.uri, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())));